# the word "succession"

Tags: word-usage

> The past of the system is conceived as no more than the continuous
>   succession of its states of presence.

I know that the word "succession" have a meaning of "something that comes after". So I think that whenever there is a sentence with the word "succession", it should have this form:  **"A" succession of "Something that happened before A".** However, in the given sentence, it says "past of the system" in front of the word "succession" and "states of presence" at the back which seems like a reverse form of what I suggested. So it sounds awkward for me. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *succession* is not "something that comes after" something else: it is the fact that one or more things follow each other: a "sequence".

So "continuous succession of states" is a sequence of states, the fact that states follow each other: one state, then another state, then another, and so forth.

The author conceives the history of a system as an ordered list of states. Think of it as movie footage: each frame of the film represents a momentary state.